# Windows/Mac client compatible with Empathy's "People Nearby" function

Tags: ubuntu, lan, instant-messaging, empathy

In Empathy (the Ubuntu IM program) you can talk to other people on your LAN with the "People nearby" function.

I'd like to use this at work, but the other PC's there are mostly Windows, and some Macs. Are there clients for those OS's compatible with this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried Bonjour myself but Pidgin is meant to support Bonjour on windows.

http://www.pidgin.im/

Answer (score 0):

iChat uses [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28protocol%29) to provide local network chat discovery.  Empathy apparently supports this [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy_%28software%29).

Answer (score 0):

In mac you can connect to Empathy People Nearby local chat group by adding local [Adium](https://adium.im/) bonjour account.